# Unsuccessful malloc?

Tags: c, malloc, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to fill an array of structures with data from a file and allocating the memory with `malloc()`. The array size is around 500 and the memory allocated in each iteration is from 2 to 6 bytes. It works perfectly on Windows XP but when I run it on Windows 7 x64 `malloc` returns null always in the iteration 109. I can't be out of RAM because I got 8Gb.
Any idea what could it be or how to fix it?

edit: Here is the code

```
typedef struct
{
    char mnemo[5];
    char *op1;
    char *op2;
    int tam;
    int codigo;
}instruction;
```

...

```
    while(!feof(archivo))
{

    fscanf(archivo,"%s",Tabla[i].mnemo);
    fscanf(archivo,"%s",ops);
    if(strchr(ops,',')==NULL){
        Tabla[i].op1=(char *)malloc(strlen(ops)+1);
        strcpy(Tabla[i].op1,ops);
        Tabla[i].op2=NULL;
    }
    else{
        Tabla[i].op1=(char *)malloc(strchr(ops,',')-ops+1);
        strncpy(Tabla[i].op1,ops,strchr(ops,',')-ops);
        Tabla[i].op1[strchr(ops,',')-ops]=0;
        ops=strchr(ops,',')+1;
        Tabla[i].op2=(char *)malloc(strlen(ops)+1);
        strcpy(Tabla[i].op2,ops);
    }
    fscanf(archivo,"%s",codigo);
    Tabla[i].codigo=(int)strtol(codigo,NULL,2);
    fscanf(archivo,"%d",&Tabla[i].tam);
    //printf("\n%s %s %s %x %d",Tabla[i].mnemo,Tabla[i].op1,Tabla[i].op2,Tabla[i].codigo,Tabla[i].tam);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some small self contained example code of what you are actually doing?

Comment: could you pls share the piece of code that has this allocation ?

Comment: possibly you're using 32bit C++ compiler, change the compiler options

Comment: This looks purely C. avoid typecasting malloc return pointer.

Comment: it is C not c++, i tryed to activate the -athlon64 compiler flag in codeblocks and without the typecasting in malloc, but nothing change still crash on iteration 109

Comment: Verify (and log) the lengths you're actually trying to malloc. You've got a lot of places where ill-formed data could really give you trouble, for example `malloc(strlen(ops)+1)` -- if a buffer overrun wipes out the '\0' at the end of `ops`, you're in trouble. The `fscanf` with a %s format into a char[5] is pretty scary too...

Comment: Can you check the value of errno as mentioned in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I actually went as far as adding code to make this compile, and creating an "archivo" file. No errors. So it seems that any errors are in the parts of the program that you have deleted. Remember: When asking a question, try to give not the parts of a program that you think contain the problem, but a _minimal_, _compilable_ example, that _still exhibits the problem_! This is especially important when you have malloc problems, since they can be caused by memory corruption in another part of the program.

Comment: there is not more code except for the declaration of the variables and the return statement after all, the size of the arrays is right cause i'm always reading lines with this format "LD B,C 01000001 1" (i'm writing an assembly for a Z80 processor) and this is to load the instructions.
It also work perfectly for me when runing in other OS but windows 7

Comment: Have you included `stdlib.h`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this statement:

```
ops=strchr(ops,',')+1;
```

This might not work across platforms due to the memory and pointer layout. 
You could try it with

```
ops=strchr(ops,','); ops++;
```

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually that works pretty well, after many tries i found that the problem is the malloc returning null